# Python Retrieve Dictionary with List from File

Tags: python

Hello i have a dictionary file named output.csv created by a dictionary with key:List and has the following form

```
A,['TEST1']

B,['TEST2']

C,"['TEST1', 'TEST3']"

D,['TEST2']

E,"['TEST1', 'TEST2']"
```

Now i try to access it from a different python script by using the following

```
reader = csv.reader(open('output.csv', 'r'))
d = {}
for row in reader:
   k, v = row
   d[k] = v
```

Although i get this error

```
line 9, in <module>
    k, v = row
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Why double quotes are not there around `TEST1` and `TEST2`?

Comment: Good question. But the initial script where i have my Dict file does not produce double quotes for these cases

Comment: Do the leading numbers `1,2,3,4,5...` actually exist in the file?

Comment: They are not numbers they are some text as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create the dictionary back you can do:

```
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open('output.csv'))
d = {}
for row in reader:
  if row:
    k = row[0]
    v = row[1]
    d[k] = v
print d
```

Output:

```
{'A': "['TEST1']", 'B': "['TEST1' 'TEST3']", 'C': "['TEST2']",
 'D': "['TEST1' 'TEST2']", 'E': "['TEST2']"}
```

EDIT (a little explaining):
This works because the delimiter value for csv.reader() defaults to `,` so it returns a list with two elements in your case. You can of course set it to something else if you want, I just assumed you want to split it by commas. To set it to something else you can do:

```
csv.reader(open('output.csv'), delimiter=']')
```

Comment: well, I ignored the empty lines. +1 ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have empty lines and possibly some lines with spaces, which get csv-unpacked as no values or one value, respectively. Add a line to ignore those:

```
for row in reader:
    if len(row)!=2: continue
    k, v = row
```